# UWP XAML: Bindings.Update() doesn't trigger inner items

Tags: uwp-xaml

If I have GridView items with `x:Bind` bindings, calling `Bindings.Update()` has no effect. None of the Items bound properties is read again. It's stuck on the values of first initialization.

But Bindings.Update() works flawless with triggering top-level re-reads of Bound properties (like `Width="{x:Bind GridWidth}"`). I call the Bindings.Update() at the Page resize event.

How can I force Xaml to re-read the items properties? The items list itself hasn't changed (list count/content), only *some* of the items properties (like `Width="{x:Bind ItemWidth}"`).

Example:

```xml
<!-- Working, re-read -->
<Grid Width="{x:Bind GridWidth}">
    <GridView x:Name="barGrid" ItemsSource="{x:Bind projects}" Background="Aqua" Grid.Row="0">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="DoubleBars" x:DataType="local:Project">
                <!-- This isn't re-read !!! !!! !!! -->
                <StackPanel x:Name="projectItemStack" Width="{x:Bind ItemWidth}" Background="Orange">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="RedBar" Fill="Red"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Test0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Margin="0, 3, 0, 5">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="GreenBar" Fill="Lime"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Test1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>

        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate/>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>

    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using x:Bind in your WPF project? Is your app a UWP app? Where is the `Bindings.Update()` method, I can not see this method? Please clarify your issue more clrear.

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT Done. If you look at the XAML you could see the x:Bind already in the first version, directly under the comments.

Comment: x:Bind should only work in UWP apps, so do you mean that you want to implement updating UI in WPF app? Or in UWP app?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes, I thought WPF was a synonym for XAML, well: It isn't. I corrected that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement that property change updates from a bound Object(Project class), you must make the Object(Project class) implement [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged) and make the Property subscribe the [PropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged) event, meanwhile, you should also specific that the x:Bind mode to be OneWay or a TwoWay. More details about binding in UWP app, you can learn from [Data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/) topic.

To clarify it, I create a sample base on your xaml code.

Here is the `Project` class that implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged).

```cs
public class Project:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double itemWidth;
    public double ItemWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return itemWidth;
        }
        set
        {
            itemWidth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemWidth");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In the xaml, I change your code to add a Button to change the Project's property and set the x:Bind mode to be **OneWay**, more about the differences, please see [BindingMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.bindingmode) Enum.

```xml
<Grid Width="{x:Bind GridWidth}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridView x:Name="barGrid" ItemsSource="{x:Bind projects,Mode=OneWay}" Background="Aqua" Grid.Row="0">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="DoubleBars" x:DataType="local:Project">
                <!-- This isn't re-read !!! !!! !!! -->
                <StackPanel x:Name="projectItemStack" Width="{x:Bind ItemWidth,Mode=OneWay}" Background="Orange">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="RedBar" Fill="Red"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Test0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Margin="0, 3, 0, 5">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="GreenBar" Fill="Lime"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Test1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>

        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate/>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>

    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Click me to change the Items width"/>
</Grid>
```

This is the page.xaml.cs code behind,

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>();
        projects.Add(new Project { ItemWidth = 300 });
        projects.Add(new Project { ItemWidth = 400 });
        projects.Add(new Project { ItemWidth = 500 });
        projects.Add(new Project { ItemWidth = 600 });
        projects.Add(new Project { ItemWidth = 700 });
    }

    ObservableCollection<Project> projects;
    public double GridWidth { get; set; } = 1000;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var item in projects)
        {
            item.ItemWidth += 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can see the change when you click the Button and change the `ItemWidth` property.

Comment: Thanks, that's working. I knew this `Mode=OneWay. INotifyPropertyChanged` etc way existed, but really didn't want to use this long-winded solution. Especially with a max. of 4 items in the list (not performance critical at all). Plus: The documentation for the INotifyPropertyChanged solution was not intuitive and seemed incomplete, scattered in multiple parts, hard to get the whole picture, at least the stuff I found. With your example it was of course much easier. Thanks for that.

Comment: `Binding` with `INotifyPropertyChanged` is the way we recommended to update the UI when the property changed in UWP app and it has better performance.